# Doubt with Absolute Value Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value, functional-inequalities

Problem:

> Find all values of $x$ for which $\dfrac{|x-2|}{x-2}>0$

My incorrect attempt:

Using the definition the Modulus, $|x-2|=x-2$ for all $x\ge2$ and $|x-2|=-x+2$ for all $x\le2.$
Splitting into 2 cases:

$$\text{CASE } 1:x\in [2,\infty)\Rightarrow |x-2|=x-2$$

$\dfrac{x-2}{x-2}>0$
$$\Rrightarrow x\in [2,\infty)\cap \mathbb{R}-\text{{2}}$$
$$\Rightarrow x\in(2,\infty)$$
$$$$
$$\text{CASE } 2:x\in(-\infty,2)\Rightarrow |x-2|=2-x$$
$$\Rightarrow \dfrac{2-x}{x-2}>0$$$$$$
On drawing the 'Wavy Curve Method' (also known as the Method of Intervals) for this, I got $x=-2,2$ as the critical points where the function changes its sign. With this, I got that the function $\dfrac{2-x}{x-2}$ is greater than $0$ in the interval $(2,2)$ and is less than $0$ for $x\in (-\infty,-2)\cup(2,\infty).$ $$$$Also, if we multiply $\dfrac{2-x}{x-2}>0$ by $-1$, then we get $\dfrac{x-2}{x-2}<0$ which is an obvious contradiction with the first case.$$$$I would be truly grateful if somebody could please clear my doubts and show me my errors. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're way over thinking this. Since $|x-2|\geq 0$ for all $x$, we just need to find when $x-2>0$. Add $2$ to both sides to get the answer:

$$x\gt 2$$

Comment: @BetterWorld, along these lines, what are the solutions of 

$$\frac{|y|}{y} > 0$$

They are $y > 0$. Hence avid19's answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir! I'm really sorry for my approach. But Sir, could you please tell me where I went wrong in my attempt?

Comment: @BetterWorld Please don't call me sir, and don't apologize for your attempt. Your mistake is $\frac{2-x}{x-2}>0$ which is never true.

Comment: @avid19 Sorry for that. It's just that out of respect I call everybody Sir on this forum. I managed to work out a reason for applying the Wavy Curve in the first case. The critical point is evidently$0.$ However, if we look at $\dfrac{x-2}{x-2},$ it is actually $(x-2)^0.$ Hence, the function never crosses the $X-axis$ since the power to which the factor is raised is $0$ ie it is a double point. However, I cannot understand how to extend this argument to the second case without multiplying both  sides by $-1.$ Could you please help me?.

Comment: Also, could you please explain why the second case is wrong?I'm not doubting it - I just would like to know if the reason for it being so could be extended to a general case.

Comment: @BetterWorld  Observe that $\frac{2 - x}{x - 2} = \frac{-1(-2 + x)}{x - 2} =  -\frac{x - 2}{x - 2} = -1$.

Comment: @SimonS what about inequality like x-a/|x|-a is there any such general form ? https://pasteboard.co/ou74fSXttpSm.jpg I am going wrong here because of that

Answer (score 1):

Note: $+$ is positive, $-$ is negative, $0$ is zero. 
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{|x-2|} & \text{x-2} & \frac {|x-2|}{x-2}\\ \hline
(-\infty,2) & + & - & (+)\div(-)=-\\ \hline
x=2 & 0 & 0 & 0\div0=\text {undefined}\\ \hline
(2,\infty) & + & + & (+)\div(+)=+
\end{array}$$

Thus, $\frac {|x-2|}{x-2}$ is positive in $(2, \infty)$.
See [$\text {sgn}(x-2)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).